# Isolate the first number after a letter with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, chemistry

I am trying to parse a chemical formula that is given to me in unicode in the format `C7H19N3`

I wish to isolate the position of the first number after the letter, I.e `7` is at index 1 and `1` is at index 3. With is this i want to insert "sub" infront of the digits

My first couple attempts had me looping though trying to isolate the position of only the first numbers but to no avail.

I think that Regular expressions can accomplish this, though im quite lost in it.

My end goal is to output the formula `Csub7Hsub19Nsub3` so that my text editor can properly format it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
>>> re.sub('(\d+)', 'sub\g<1>', "C7H19N3")
'Csub7Hsub19Nsub3'
```

`(\d+)` is a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that matches 1 or more digits. `\g<1>` is a way of referring to the saved group in the substitute string.

Comment: +1, but matching one digit would be enough. In fact, matching zero digits would be, too: `re.sub(r'(?<!\d)(?=\d)', 'sub', "C7H19N3")`

Comment: @TimPietzcker ah! You modified your regex, and I posted the exact same version.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary and TimPietzcker +1 I like your solution more. :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this with lookahead and lookbehind:

```
>>> strs = 'C7H19N3'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<!\d)(?=\d)','sub',strs)
'Csub7Hsub19Nsub3'
```

This matches the following positions in the string:

```
C^7H^19N^3   # ^ represents the positions matched by the regex.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one which literally matches the first digit after a letter:

```
>>> re.sub(r'([A-Z])(\d)', r'\1sub\2', "C7H19N3")
'Csub7Hsub19Nsub3'
```

It's functionally equivalent but perhaps more expressive of the intent? `\1` is a shorter version of `\g<1>`, and I also used raw string literals (`r'\1sub\2'` instead of `'\1sub\2'`).